# How to replace this?

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to replace the name of my input tag to another for coding purposes. here is my default text in my name at input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="def" id="def">
```

I want to become the *def* = *defense*

The reason i want to do this is because I designed *def* for coding on php, I want to `echo defense not as def` (because they will know what I typed in the php scripts.

Comment: where you want to replace? while posting or while displaying @render time?

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask.

Comment: OP needs something like: `echo preg_replace('/name="def"/', 'name="defense"', $str);`

Comment: @FrayneKonok i should type this ? `$str = <input type="text" name="def" id="def">`

Comment: @Thamilan, if the errors pops out, it is like, `defense is required` not `def is required`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_replace` here, I know this is not the best way, But your purpose will be done.

```
$str = '<input type="text" name="def" id="def">';
$str = preg_replace('/name="def"/', 'name="defense"', $str);
```

Comment: it worked, but the data in the `$str` does not saved when replacement is done.

Comment: you need to store it back to the `$str`

Comment: this is my whole problem. the `$_POST['def']` , will get, and then when I validate it, it is validated as def, what I want to try is `def as defense` so that when, the validation has received an error, it will result as `defense is required` ? thanks